# Deploy multiple WARs on OpenShift

Tags: java, war, openshift

I am new to Openshift. However I have two questions here...

1. I want to deploy multiple WAR files with their separate context roots on Openshift.
2. I want to publish all dependency JAR libraries to the default classpath of Tomcat on Openshift.

I tried the forums, but with little help. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

An EAR file can contain WAR files, JAR files, EJB's and other archives. If you add multiple WAR files inside of your EAR file, they will each be deployed at their individual context. Any libraries added as JAR files should be made available to all applications that are deployed inside of your EAR file, but not any other EAR files that have been deployed.

https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear

Answer (score 0):

One way I would do is using docker containers with their own war files and then use YAML configuration to pull the image and run the containers on OpenShift.

However, you could also do something called source-to-image where OpenShift will build and deploy them for you.  But I think you could also look at the templates that are provided for you by your devops team and find your options too.

Comment: Note that based on the date, the original question was about OpenShift 2, which is quite different to OpenShift 3 which you are talking about.